# How to insert array of Object in to mysql with node js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am new to node js .I am pretty confused that how to insert array of object in to mysql with nodejs

My Code

```
static inserPost(postCardArray,postTitle,postedDate,username,coords){
      //postCardArray = [ {hello:'dude'} ]
        let query = "INSERT INTO ??(??,??,??,??,??,??) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        let inserts = ["post","post_by_username","title","post_body","posted_date","views","coords",`${username}`,`${postTitle}`,`${postCardArray}`,`${postedDate}`,0,`${coords}`];
        query = mysql.format(query,inserts);
        pool.getConnection((err,connection) => {
            if(err)
                throw err
            else
                connection.query(query,(err,rows) => {
                    connection.release();
                    console.log(rows)
                })
        })

    }
```

But Above Code inserts the data like this [Object] I don't know how to insert .

Comment: (Just an aside question for the well-versed... is this the preferred way to prepare statements in Node,js?)

Comment: yup I think so https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#preparing-queries

Comment: What is the value of `query` after running it through `mysql.format(query, inserts)`?

Comment: It will Simply Print out Fully Modified Mysql Query @cale_b

Comment: @Nane - You miss my point.  It SHOULD print it, did you pass in the correct parameters? What DOES it print?  Use `console.log()` or your debugger and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you are using new ES6 string templateing which internally will call `toString` method on your object, so you should check your variable values of this part of code

```
`${username}`,`${postTitle}`,`${postCardArray}`,`${postedDate}`,0,`${coords}`
```

Basically `toString` method of plain object will return string `"[object Object"]` instead of key value pairs.
Also you can look at `JSON.stringify` method, which will create JSON string of your object

I would suggest you to use ORM instead to build valid queries, such as [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/), [Bookshelf](http://bookshelfjs.org/) with [Knex](http://knexjs.org/) or [node-orm2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2)
.

Comment: ORMs might Fail at some Difficult queries !!

Comment: @Nane can you show please values of your variables, since we don't know what is your values and can't advice and solution without them.

Comment: Between if you have difficult queries, you can use raw queries with ORM, instead of built in methods, for example sequelize provides good API for that http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/raw-queries/, though if your app is small you can use just node mysql without any ORM

Comment: Anyways I found the Solution I Have to Parse My Json Array Objects Like this **JSON.Stringify()**

Comment: Great  that you found it,I am happy that somehow helped you!